# jomsocial module facebook connect not working on other pages

Tags: joomla, facebook

I m able to login into the website via FB if i m on the home page of the jomsocial,

but when i m on the pages of the website, then if i want to try using that button, it's not able to bring the popup window of facebook to login.

Please help

thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: What login module are you using? Is it the same module in Jomsocial as the rest of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem,

thanks anyways!!!!

it was only the appid was missing form the code.

Comment: Hi Dave
I am also getting exactly same issue. can you please explain me how you got your problem solved? may be it will help to to sort out my issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: inside administrator, jomsocial>configuration>facebookconnect
there you need to supply your appid and appsecret key. and it'll work for sure

Answer (score 0):

That's usually caused when another extensions is also trying to load the Facebook library in addition to JomSocial. Search the HTML of your page for appId. This should be the Facebook application ID you're using in JomSocial, and it should only come up once in the page like:
appId: '12345'

If it comes up twice, or especially is different both times, then there's likely going to be confusion when communicating with Facebook.

Also look for any instances of "featureloader.js.php". This is Facebook's very old library, which is incompatible with the new one (all.js). If it's in there, that's another extension you'll have to remove.

Finally, if you're using an extension like JFBConnect, which has additional Facebook features and functionality over JomSocial, you'll simply want to remove the API/Secret keys from JomSocial and configure JFBConnect like normal. That will disable JomSocial so it doesn't conflict with JFBConnect.

For more information about JFBConnect, see:
[Joomla Facebook Connect](http://joomla-facebook.com)

Answer (score 0):

If your Joomsocial component is old then there is issue in code level I solved
by this 
in file components\com_community\controllers\connect.php in function changes code in else part like this

```
           function ajaxUpdate{
           if(){
             //same as it is
            }
           } else {

        $my = CFactory::getUser($connectTable->userid);
        //$myuser = JFactory::getUser($connectTable->userid);
        $myuser = new JUser($connectTable->userid);
        if (COwnerHelper::isCommunityAdmin($connectTable->userid)) {

            $tmpl = new CTemplate();
            $content = $tmpl->fetch('facebook.link.notallowed');
            $buttons = '<input type="button" value="' . JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_BUTTON_CLOSE_BUTTON') . '" class="btn" onclick="cWindowHide();" />';
            $response->addScriptCall('cWindowAddContent', $content, $buttons);
            return $response->sendResponse();
        }else{

        }

        // Generate a joomla password format for the user so we can log them in.
        $password = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword();

        $userData = array();
        $userData['password'] = $password;
        $userData['password2'] = $password;

        if (!$myuser->bind($userData)) {
            echo $myuser->getError(); die();
        }
        if (!$myuser->save()) {
            echo $myuser->getError(); die();
        }


        //$my->bind($userData);




        // User object must be saved again so the password change get's reflected.
        //$my->save();
        //$myuser->save();


        $mainframe->login(array('username' => $my->username, 'password' => $password));

        if ($config->get('fbloginimportprofile')) {

            $this->_facebook->mapProfile($userInfo, $my->id);

        }

        $tmpl = new CTemplate();
        $tmpl->set('my', $my);
        $tmpl->set('userInfo', $userInfo);


        $content = $tmpl->fetch('facebook.existinguser');
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($content);  
        $actions = '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="joms.connect.importData();" value="' . JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_CONTINUE_BUTTON') . '"/>';

        // Update page token since the userid is changed now.
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $token = $session->getFormToken(false);

        $response->addScriptCall('jax_token_var="' . $token . '";');

        // Add invite button
        $response->addAssign('cwin_logo', 'innerHTML', $config->get('sitename'));
        $response->addScriptCall('cWindowAddContent', $content, $actions);
        //die();
        $response->sendResponse();
    }
```

}